# Proxy URL issue for Media Library Items in Sitecore Rich Text Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am having an issue regarding the media library item URLs in the Rich Text editor

Currently we have set up our site as

- www.mysite.com - for public content
- cms.mysite.com - for Sitecore admin (This is a proxy URL which can be accessed within internally)

It works perfectly except that when Saving the content in the Rich Text editor, all URLs to the media library items (PDF, images) will be converted using the path "http://cms.mysite.com". We always have to go to the HTML View to manually remove all the cms.mysite.com URL - which is a pain.

The links to the content items/pages are fine. Only the links to the media library items will be converted during the save.

The Staging Module is not used so I wonder if there is a configuration to disable the conversion or do something to stop the URL conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Revoked original response as I found I was wrong.

At least in 6.3.x and onwards, the RTE doesn't appear to store the hostname in the media links. What version are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately we are using 6.2.0. Even editing the existing content, the RTE will add the hostname to all the media library item paths.